# The monoid of lists of morphisms in a category subject to commuting diagrams

Tags: ct.category-theory

Start with a category $C$. Form a monoid $M$ whose elements are lists of morphisms in the category $C$ subject to commuting diagrams in $C$. Is there a name for this construction or a better way to categorially understand this?

Comment: if you consider  lists of morphisms in a category $\mathcal{C}$, how can you compose these (and get a monid)? Then I guess you consider  concatenated morphisms, but this isnt a monoid (if there is more than one object) in general these are the morphims of the free category associated to the  graph of $\mathcal{C}$, then if you identify two of its arrow if as sequence of morphisms   have some composition in $\mathcal{C}$  (i.e. these two make a commutative diagram) in this way you get (but a  isomorphism functor) the category $\mathcal{C}$.



Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean take the monoid with the following presentation?  Take the arrows of C as generators and add the relations that f.g = fg if f and g are composable and that each identity of C be equivalent to 1?  I would call this the universal monoid U(C) of C. It has the universal property that there is a functor $F:C\to U(C)$ (the obvious one) such that any functor from C to a monoid M, viewed as a one-object category, factors through $U(C)$.  So U is the left adjoint to the inclusion of the category of monoids into the category of small categories.

I myself have used the group version of this many times.

Comment: Ah, this seems to fit to the question.

Comment: Ah, oh so there is a group version and a monoid version. Indeed universal monoid is a good name for it. Thanks. This is indeed what I was looking for.

Comment: Should every identity arrow be made equivalent to 1? Perhaps a pointed version is better, and only the identity arrow of the point be made equivalent to 1.

Comment: You could not identify any identity with 1 and get the universal semi functor to a semigroup.  

Answer (score 2):

For every $n$ we have the set $N_n(C)$ of $n$-chains $X_0 \to \dotsb \to X_n$ of morphisms in $X$. This set is actually a category, the morphisms are commutative diagrams. A short definition is $N_n(C) = \mathrm{Hom}([n],C)$, where the preorder $[n] = \{0,\dotsc,n\}$ is considered as a category. In fact, $\{N_n(C)\}_n$ is a [simplicial set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_set), called the [nerve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nerve_%28category_theory%29) of $C$. It's geometric realization is also called the geometric realization $|C|$ of $C$.

In your question, you obviously vary $n$ and want to get a single monoid. It's not clear to me how you want to achieve this. Perhaps you really mean the nerve, or do you want to consider $\coprod_n N_n(C)$?